# How can I Create folders recursively in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, recursion, mkdir

Need some help in creating function which can create folders recursively with giving path:

```
C:\TestFolder\Another\AndAnother
```

Delphi function MkDir returning IOerror = 3.

```
MkDir('C:\TestFolder\Another\AndAnother');
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use

```
ForceDirectories('C:\TestFolder\Another\AndAnother');
```

(This is a standard RTL function, found in SysUtils.pas. Hence you do not need to create your own function, even though that wouldn't have been difficult.)

Comment: Writing your own `ForceDirectories` that works on your computer: *easy*. Writing one that works in the wild handling all the edge cases: *hard*

Comment: exactly, all the edge cases make it hard.

Comment: This is not UNC aware, this is why I recommend the new IOUtils library.

Answer (score 4):

SysUtils is obsolete now and ForceDirectories is not UNC aware!

There is a new library in since Delphi XE7 (or even earlyer?) called IOUtils.
IOUtils is cross-platform compatible and UNC aware.

```
function ForceDirectories(FullPath: string): Boolean;   // Works with UNC paths
begin
  TDirectory.CreateDirectory(FullPath);
  Result:= DirectoryExists(FullPath);
end;
```

Note: The function is from [Delphi LightSaber](https://github.com/GodModeUser/Delphi-LightSaber-CoreLib/blob/main/ccIO.pas) library. There are several other similar I/O functions there (like ListFilesOf(Folder)).

Comment: if we're going to use System.IOUtils, shouldn't we at least use `TDirectory.Exists` instead of `DirectoryExists` from SysUtils?

Comment: You are right. but only for the sake of using modern code. DirectoryExists still works (and still not marked as deprecated by Emba). 
PS: The code looks like this because it is a very very old piece of code from my LightSaber library. This was one of the very first pieces of code in that lib. Back then, IOUtils was very crappy. I mean seriously flawed. So, I tried to use as little as possible from IOUtils.

Comment: Anyway, TDirectory.Exists still did not fixed some issues that DirectoryExists had:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166420/delphi-directoryexists-function-odd-behaviour-for-network-mapped-units

Answer (score 0):

create "folder #1"
create "folder #2" inside "folder #1"
TDirectory.copy("folder #1","folder #2");
and watch the fun.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).