# Win32 CreateDirectory fails with multiple folders in a long path

Tags: delphi, create-directory

The environment is Windows 7 Pro and Delphi 7.

`Windows.CreateDirectory()` is failing to create multiple folders in a very long path that is well under the path length limit.  `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.

The failure is the same on an ESXi virtual machine, as well as a native Win7 workstation and physical disk.  A similar failure occurs with `Windows.MoveFile()`.

The long path in the code below is created correctly in a CMD window as a pasted parameter to `MKDIR`.

My work-around is creating this long path piece-meal. I split the path at the '\' character into a string array. Then I loop through the array and build the cumulative path from each element. The loop correctly builds the full path without an error.

I have no clue why the Win32 function fails to create a valid long path.

```pascal
var
  arrDstPath : TStringArray;
begin
  // --------------
  // failing method
  // --------------
  strDstPath := 'C:\Duplicate Files\my customer recovered data\desktop\my customer name\application data\gtek\gtupdate\aupdate\channels\ch_u3\html\images\';

  if (Windows.CreateDirectory(pchar(strDstPath),nil) = false) then
    Result := Windows.GetLastError;  // #3 is returned
  if (DirectoryExists(strNewPath) = false) then
    Result := ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND;

  // -----------------
  // successful method
  // -----------------
  strNewPath := '';
  LibSplitToArray(arrDstPath,'\',strDstPath);
  for intIdx := 0 to High(arrDstPath) do
  begin
    strNewPath := strNewPath + arrDstPath[intIdx] + '\';
    Windows.CreateDirectory(PChar(strNewPath), nil);
  end;

  if (DirectoryExists(strDstPath) = false) then       // compare to original path string
  begin
    Result := ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND;
    Exit;
  end;
```

Comment: Just an off-topic hint: Instead of `if DirectoryExists(mydir) = False then`, you can write `if not DirectoryExists(mydir) then`. Most people find that easier to read.

Comment: It's called `CreateDirectory` for a reason, and not `CreatePath`: it only creates ONE directory, not several.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the official documentation for the [`CreateDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya) function describes what's going on. Since the function fails, your instinct should be to have a look at the section describing the return value, which states:

> **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS**
>
> The specified directory already exists.
>
> **ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND**
>
> One or more intermediate directories do not exist; this function will only create the final directory in the path.

I assume you got `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, and the documentation suggests a probable reason: you are attempting to create several levels of subdirectories at once, which the function doesn't support.

Fortunately, the Delphi RTL has the [`ForceDirectories`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ForceDirectories) function that can create subdirectories recursively. ([How can I Create folders recursively in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231044/how-can-i-create-folders-recursively-in-delphi))

In Delphi 2010 and later, you can also use [`TDirectory.CreateDirectory`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory) from `IOUtils.pas`. Internally, this calls `ForceDirectories`.

Comment: Note that the Win32 Shell API has `SHCreateDirectory/Ex()` functions that create missing intermediate folders for you, similar to `ForceDirectories()`. The difference being, `ForceDirectories()` calls `CreateDirectory()` in a (non-recursive) loop, whereas `SHCreateDirectory/Ex()` is a single call

Comment: I was very clear about using Delphi 7, not Delphi 10.
I write the long hand notation because I do not care for the lesser clarity of  the "If Not"... construct.

What is threw me for a loop is the inability of the CreateDirectory() function to create a deep path, as does the MKDIR function in the command shell.

ForceDirectories function exists in D7, but it is not mentioned in my CreateDirectory docs.

My Win32 SDK documentation has the CreateDirectoryEx, but no mention is made of creating a deep path in a single call.
Since I am the one reading the code, I write it as I prefer.

Comment: And thanks to all who pointed out the underlying reason why this call fails on a deep path.

This is another gotcha I will add to my list of function call gotchas...

Comment: @BruceGavin: I know you are using Delphi 7; the reason I mentioned Delphi 2010's `TDirectory.CreateDirectory` is for the benefit of other readers of this Q who have searched Google for the same issue! Half the point of Stack Overflow is to help googlers. :) I very much didn't want to offend or upset you. I am sorry if I did. The reason the `CreateDirectory` documentation doesn't mention `ForceDirectories` is that `CreateDirectory` is a function in Microsoft Windows, while `ForceDirectories` is a function in Embarcadero's Delphi, and Microsoft has no connection to Embarcadero.